# Flutter Agora blurry video

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am using Flutter [agora_rtc_engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine) for live broadcasting.
We had a live video broadcasting with around 10 viewers. Every viewer faced blurry video.
Can anyone suggest any hints to avoid blurry video? Is there a configuration which can be tried in Flutter agora_rtc_engine?
Thanks

Comment: You may need to upgrade your account to premium.

Comment: Thanks @YunusEmreÇelik. Is this documented anywhere by Agora.io? that is upgrade to premium for better video quality?

Comment: I see this setting in some examples, can this make any difference? AgoraRtcEngine.setParameters('{\"che.video.lowBitRateStreamParameter\":{\"width\":320,\"height\":180,\"frameRate\":15,\"bitRate\":140}}');

Comment: @KrishnaShetty The low-stream parameter applies to instances where you are using dual stream mode. You should not need to modify this parameter because it is meant to optimize the bandwidth for various scenarios. You can force low stream mode to save on bandwidth when the stream is not the main view (floating view format) or when there are more than 4 participants (grid view)

Comment: @KrishnaShetty, you do not have to upgrade your account. What video resolution are you setting?

Comment: @Hermes sorry for the delay in response.  How do I set video resolution for the live broadcasting(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting)? How to make video non blurry incase of low data bandwidth network?  The blurry video was observed with low bandwidth 4G network.